# Is there some special meaning to `[foo]` right after `from bar import foo` in python? (perhaps python2 specific)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, syntactic-sugar

In particular, I am looking at this code:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import IntegrityError
[IntegrityError]
```

and am wondering: Is there some special meaning to `[IntegrityError]`?

IntegrityError is just a class defined in the sqlite3 package, and of course, my own interpretation is that `[IntgrityError]` would just be an expression that puts it in a list, yet there I have it in a piece of code that I am studying. Could it be a typo? or am I missing some magic syntactic-sugar interpretation?

Comment: Where did you find this code? If it's publicly available, it might be useful if you included a link to it.

Comment: No, I think it's just doing nothing. It *could* be fishing for a `ReferenceError` or something in importing the error (such that referencing it would raise an error), and it would make sense to do that before setting anything else up - but otherwise, I think that line of code does exactly what you think it does, i.e. nothing.

Comment: It creates a list with one object… and then discards it immediately…

Comment: Honestly, it looks like another language's style. I cannot remember exactly which language...

Comment: It turns out this is an internal API check + linter squelching. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `from sqlite3 import IntegrityError` ensures that DB-API 2.0 (PEP-249) version of sqlite3 is on the system, and the subsequent line [IntegrityError] squelches the linter.